# Can't change primary color in Understrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, theme-development

My changes in _theme_variables.scss are not visible, don't know why.

I tried to change the primary color in assets/bootstrap4/_variables.scss but nothing happened unfortunately. If anyone knows how how to use Understrap for WordPress plz show me how to solve the colors issue.

Answer (score -1):

Understrap is a WordPress theme framework based on Bootstrap. It comes with predefined styles and settings, including a primary color, which is not easily customizable out of the box. Changing the primary color in Understrap requires modifying the theme's CSS files or using custom CSS overrides. It is recommended to create a child theme or use a custom CSS plugin to make the changes. Alternatively, there are other WordPress themes or frameworks available that offer more flexibility in customizing the primary color without extensive coding.